Dimensions of matrix from other properties?
If we are given some matrix $A$ and we know it is a square matrix, could we get its size from other relevant numbers associated to it?
For example, the "number of eigenvalues" doesn't give (always) the right answer, but maybe a complicated expression with the trace, determinant, the sequence $A, A^2, \cdots, A^N, \cdots$
I assume there is not such a thing but

Is it reasonable to think that it exists? I'm inclined to think that it could even be proved that such a thing doesn't exist
Does it exist if we impose conditions on $A$ (triangular, diagonal, orthogonal...)
Is there a formula for the rank?

Thanks in advance!

This seems difficult in general. Since you don't know the size, you can't apply it to vectors. I don't see how you can tell the difference between, e.g., the $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ zero matrices without some reference to an ambient vector space. Orthogonal and invertible cases are pretty easy though, $n = \mathrm{tr}(A^{-1}A)$.

You could use rank nullity theorem to get a formula that works in the non-invertible case, but I'm not sure if that's in the spirit of your question.
